# How to automatically start XMRig on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, xmrig

I am running xmrig-5.8.1 on Ubuntu 18.04  by executing this cmd `./xmrig --donate-level 1 -o pool.supportxmr.com:xyz -u MY-XMR-ADDRES -p Rig1 -k --tls`. Now I want it to start automatically in background whenever I start my system. I found some way like adding a script file inside `init`  or `init.d` folder but I don't know how to add the script file inside these folder and what to add inside these script file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *many* ways to do this. One simple way is via cron:

In a shell execute `crontab -e` then add and edit the line:

```
@reboot /path/to/xmrig -B [--syslog | --log-file=/some/file.log] [your other options]
```

Save and exit.

The `-B` option runs it in the background and you add either the `--syslog` or `--log-file` option so you can get at its output.

Many other Ubuntu examples of running things at startup here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: my xmrig file is in `home/user/xmrig5.8/xmrig` So it should be done like this
 `@reboot home/user/xmrig5.8/xmrig -B [--log-file=/some/file.log]` 
so then what is the use of this cmd 
`./xmrig --donate-level 1 -o pool.supportxmr.com:xyz -u MY-XMR-ADDRES -p Rig1 -k --tls` @jtgrassie

Comment: `@reboot /home/user/xmrig5.8/xmrig -B --log-file=/some/file.log --donate-level 1 -o pool.supportxmr.com:xyz -u MY-XMR-ADDRES -p Rig1 -k --tls`

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `su - user -c bla bla..` ?

Comment: Depends which users crontab was edited and which user it is wanted to be run as. Also, you don't need to use `su` in crontabs as you can just place the user name between the time section and command. e.g. `@reboot bob /home/bob/xmrig ...`.

Comment: `home/user/xmrig5.8/xmrig` this is my xmrig file path find you own and add this in startup application this worked for me 100% it will work for you also.